# How can i use simplest Task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, task

I'm talking about <strike>single-threaded (not TaskEx for WindowsPhone)</strike> (ok, even basic Task is designed to be async, this makes question senseless) and synchronous (no async/await) pure `Task`.

Can in be useful in some cases (i have quite common app which pulls data from the server, deserialize it and shows results), or is `Task` just a basement for

```
await TaskEx.Run()?
```

EDIT1: i mean, how this

```
void Foo()
{
    DoSmth();
}

void Main()
{
    int a = 1;
    Foo();
    int b = 1;
}
```

would differ from

```
void Main()
{ 
    int a = 1;
    Task.Run( () => DoSmth );
    int b = 1;
}
```

Calling `Foo();` is also kinda a "promise that next code would be called after Foo() is done".

EDIT2: I just ran in wp7 app

```
        Debug.WriteLine("OnLoaded {0} ", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Debug.WriteLine("Run Id: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            });

        Debug.WriteLine("Done");
```

Got the output:

```
OnLoaded 1 
Done
Run Id: 4
```

So, is `Task.Factory.StartNew()` the same as `TaskEx.Run()` ?

---

ESIT3: so, here is a short summary (as `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is the same as `TaskEx.Run()`):

```
Thread.Sleep(5000); // UI is frozen for 5 seconds
int a = 1; // this is called after 5 seconds



TaskEx.Run(() => 
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); 
    int a = 1;  // this is called after 5 seconds
}
int b = 2; // UI is not frozen, this is called instantly



await TaskEx.Run(() => // UI is not frozen, but...
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); 
    int a = 1;  // this is called after 5 seconds
}
int b = 2; // this is called then task is done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Task` is just a way to represent something that will complete in the future.  This is most commonly an asynchronous operation or something running in a background thread (via `Task.Run`/`TaskEx.Run`).

A "synchronous pure `Task`" really doesn't make sense - the entire purpose of a `Task` is to represent something that is not synchronous.

> Can in be useful in some cases (i have quite common app which pulls data from the server, deserialize it and shows results),

In this case, since the data is pulling from a server, that is by its nature a good canidate for an asynchronous operation.  This would make it a perfect canidate for `Task` (or `Task<T>`).

---

In response to your edit:

In the first version, everything is just run sequentially.

The second version, using `Task.Run`, actually causes `DoSmth()` to execute in a background thread.  The `Task` returned can be used with `await` to asynchonously wait for it to complete, if you wanted to do so.  This means that `DoSmth()` will potentially run at the same time as the assignment to b (and subsequent operations).

Comment: Yea, i mean if i'd have just a normal sync function call, it would be also kinda a "promise that next code would be called after function would be finished".

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko If your function is synchronous, it would be misleading to wrap it into a `Task`.  Wrapping up synchronous code and pretending its asynchronous leads to problems...

Comment: I'm curious exactly about that "promise" part. Just edited question, can you, please, provide some details?

Comment: **the entire purpose of a Task is to represent something that is not synchronous.** - so, Task is just a basement for TaskEx ?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko There is no such thing as `TaskEx`, really - its just there because they couldn't add to the Task class until the new framework came out.  If you look at the current frameworks, `TaskEx` doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, it exists on Wp7 :) For example on wp7 platform, a common `Task` is not called in a background thread.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko No - it exists as an extra library to try to make up for the fact that the methods were added to `Task` in WP8....

Comment: I got your point, but still if i'd call `Task.Run(() => DoSmth)`, it would be executed in the same thread. At least on wp7.

Comment: Aha. Okay, my fault. Looking like normal Tasks are also running in another thread. Interesting.

Comment: Just added Edit2. But then, what's the difference between Task.Factory.StartNew() and TaskEx.Run()? Are they the same?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew are almost identical - the only difference is some configuration settings in Task.Run to prevent problems in most scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, now the last brick stands on its place :). So, by default, Task was designed to be async and that is what "promising" means.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Yes - a "Task" is essentially a representation of an operation that "promises to complete at some point".